# Is it on-topic to ask for help finding the source of a quote?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have found a quote attributed to an author, but I have been unable to locate the source of the quote. Is it on-topic to ask for help identifying the source?

In case it makes a difference, the quote is about an elephant's memory by Herb Caen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yep!**

There are several examples of such questions on the main site; e.g. [Where did the Robert Frost Quote "If we couldn't laugh, we would all go insane" come from?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5535/58), [Who said "Poetry is the art of giving different names to the same thing"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5181/58). We've even got a whole tag for it: [quote-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote-identification).

I don't think we have any explicit meta decision about it, but if you suspect that the quote is from a literary work it should be fine here (but of course, there's no way to know if it's from a literary source before finding the source, so that kinda defaults to allowing *all* quote identifications).

Of course, any clues are helpful - so who it's generally attributed to, where you found the attribution, and where you've looked.